# vmware-toolbox-cmd Command not found

Tags: vmware, redhat, rhel, esxi, vmware-tools

I'm working with a Redhat VM that indicates VMware Tools OSPs is installed and running, since its VMware Tools status in vSphere is "Running (3rd-party/Independent)".   I have also verified that the VMware Tools daemon, `vmtoolsd`, is running by running the following command ...

```
# pgrep -fl vmtoolsd

>> 6048 /usr/bin/vmtoolsd
```

However, whenever I try to run the `vmware-toolbox-cmd` command, it says command not found.  What is this VM missing that it has VMware Tools OSPs installed but does not have the command for it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no GUI interface called vmware-toolbox with vmware player 5 (and other newer products), as per [Installing and Configuring VMware Tools:](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vmware-tools-installation-configuration.pdf)

`The graphical user interface for VMware Tools, which is sometimes called the VMware Tools control panel and which is available from the notification area in the guest operating system, has been deprecated`

You can however find settings for the toolbox, say "Update automatically", in the graphical user interface of the VMWare Player on the host (as in Player -> Manage -> Virtual Machine Settings -> Options -> VMware Tools).

As for `vmware-toolbox-cmd` doesn't do anything"? You bet it does, read the doc above.